# How to find words between 2 words with re in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

The thing is that I'm scraping a website, and I want to scrape A string between two tags, (the scrape is already in str)

So I'm trying to get a phrase like this  Hello World ,

I tried doing this

```
substring = re.search("<address>(.*?)</address>", d1)
```

But I'm getting the values with the address included

Comment: Im asking in this one how it can be exclusive with address

Comment: You're trying to parse HTML with regular expressions. You can't parse HTML with regular expressions. Use a HTML parsing library instead of regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: If you access `substring.group(1)`, you should just get what is in the capture group.  But...why are you not using Beautiful Soup to parse your HTML content?

Comment: Use a XML/HTML parser

Comment: @Ibreakthings The description says "scrape a website". If that really means one website, then I don't think it's clear if a sophisticated parser would be necessary. I could imagine regex could be fine in very simple cases.